# Haskell under Jupyter

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-irkernel, ihaskell

The Internet is strangely absent of instructions on how to get Haskell running under the Jupyter environment.   Any documentation that leads you toward this requires you to compile from source, however when attempting to do so, all sorts of build errors occur.

It seems odd that an environment that would certainly give Haskell so much exposure is strangely not exercised by enough people that there would be some decent documentation.   Yet, the language is supposedly is supported.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: If you are under linux you can actually install iHaskell without building it from source, as specified in the jupyter documentation: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels#repository

Comment: I'm willing use Linux to get this.   Does anyone have full end-to-end instructions on how to get this working on Ubuntu?   Do I need to install Anaconda?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what I've done to get it up and running in Linux (Lubuntu 16.0)

Prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip git libtinfo-dev libzmq3-dev libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libmagic-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev
```

Setup IHaskell locally

```
git clone https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell.git
cd IHaskell
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh
stack install gtk2hs-buildtools
stack setup
stack install
```

Install Haskell kernal for IPython

```
stack exec -- ihaskell install --stack
```

Run Haskell in Jupyter

```
stack exec jupyter -- notebook
```

More details in: https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [Community Jupyter Docker Stacks](https://github.com/jamesdbrock/ihaskell-notebook) image for IHaskell. If you have [Docker installed](https://docs.docker.com/install/), then you can run a Haskell Jupyter notebook with one command.